# AcroPDF viewer control problems

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, adobe

I'm at the point of giving up.

I need to view pdfs in my Winforms application, so I've tried using Adobe's ActiveX control, and the vanilla WebBrowser control. The pdfs are local, and can be opened from Explorer with no problems at all.

The weird thing is that the application views the pdfs fine when running in Visual Studio, but the built application simply shows a grey area where the pdf is supposed to be. The exact same thing happens with both the Adobe control and the WebBrowser control. After a while, I usually get an Adobe error saying `There is a problem with Adobe Acrobat/Reader. If it is running, please exit and try again. (103:103)`. I've looked this error up, which advised me to do things that didn't work (turning off a security setting).

Moreover, if the WebBrowser control is called with a `.Navigate(path, true)`, the application opens an IE window that displays the pdf just fine.

I've tried running as administrator, which makes no difference. I'm at wits' end, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Maybe going for a 3rd party control?

Some further detail: I tried both Adobe 11 and Adobe DC, on Windows 10 and 8.1 VMs, .Net 4.6. Only a Win7 VM seems to work fine.

Comment: Sometimes the AxAcroPDF will leave an instance of Adobe Viewer running if not disposed of properly.  Have you checked task manager to make sure there isn't anything left hanging? I can't say if this will fix it or not, or if there is even a process left, but it's worth a quick look.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Nothing there. Restarting doesn't help either, and the same thing happens when I load pdfs in a WebBrowser control.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is maybe your AcroPDF.dll is not up to date, or your AcroPDF.dll is too new for the readers and you need to replace it with an older version.  Other than that, I'm not sure if I can suggest any extra on this situation.  Maybe try getting in contact with Adobe if all else fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I solved this by building to x86 targets. Apparently AcroPDF.dll doesn't support x64. Of course, the error messages weren't at all helpful.</s>

My previous answer was incorrect. The real issue is Adobe's Protected Startup mode. This has to be turned off for the application to use the viewer directly without problems.

Comment: I experienced this problem yesterday (came out of the blue, the program worked just fine before).  Repaired Acrobat Reader DC from the Control Panel, then unchecked Enable Protected Mode at Startup in Edit>Preferences>Security (Enhanced)